# Simulating a simple optical flow

Tags: image-processing, julia

I am currently trying to simulate an optical flow using the following equation:

[image: Continuity equation]

Below is a basic example where I have a 7x7 image where the central pixel is illuminated. The velocity I am applying is a uniform x-velocity of 2.

```
using Interpolations
using PrettyTables

# Generate grid
nx = 7  # Image will be 7x7 pixels
x = zeros(nx, nx)
yy = repeat(1:nx, 1, nx)  # grid of y-values
xx = yy'  # grid of x-values

# In this example x is the image I in the above equation
x[(nx-1)÷2 + 1, (nx-1)÷2 + 1] = 1.0  # set central pixel equal to 1

# Initialize velocity
velocity = 2;
vx = velocity .* ones(nx, nx); # vx=2
vy = 0.0      .* ones(nx, nx); # vy=0

for t in 1:1
    # create 2d grid interpolator of the image
    itp = interpolate((collect(1:nx), collect(1:nx)), x, Gridded(Linear()));

    # create 2d grid interpolator of vx and vy
    itpvx = interpolate((collect(1:nx), collect(1:nx)), vx, Gridded(Linear()));
    itpvy = interpolate((collect(1:nx), collect(1:nx)), vy, Gridded(Linear()));

    ∇I_x  = Array{Float64}(undef, nx, nx);   # Initialize array for ∇I_x
    ∇I_y  = Array{Float64}(undef, nx, nx);   # Initialize array for ∇I_y
    ∇vx_x = Array{Float64}(undef, nx, nx);  # Initialize array for ∇vx_x
    ∇vy_y = Array{Float64}(undef, nx, nx);  # Initialize array for ∇vy_y
    for i=1:nx
        for j=1:nx
            # gradient of image in x and y directions
            Gx = Interpolations.gradient(itp, i, j);
            ∇I_x[i, j] = Gx[2];
            ∇I_y[i, j] = Gx[1];
            Gvx = Interpolations.gradient(itpvx, i, j)  # gradient of vx in both directions
            Gvy = Interpolations.gradient(itpvy, i, j)  # gradient of vy in both directions
            ∇vx_x[i, j] = Gvx[2];
            ∇vy_y[i, j] = Gvy[1];
        end
    end

    v∇I = (vx .* ∇I_x) .+ (vy .* ∇I_y)  # v dot ∇I
    I∇v = x .* (∇vx_x .+ ∇vy_y) # I dot ∇v
    x = x .- (v∇I .+ I∇v)  # I(x, y, t+dt)
    pretty_table(x)
end
```

What I expect is that the illuminated pixel in `x` will shift two pixels to the right in `x_predicted`. What I am seeing is the following:
[image: applied velocity]

where the original illuminated pixel's value is moved to the neighboring pixel twice rather than being shifted two pixels to the right. I.e. the neighboring pixel goes from being 0 to 2 and the original pixel goes from a value of 1 to -1. I'm not sure if I'm messing up the equation or if I'm thinking of velocity in the wrong way here. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a calculation issue, not an image issue - the `x_predicted` matrix doesn't have the value you expect. Making it clearer that it's not a plotting issue - change the title to "Evolving a grid ...", remove the `using PyPlot` line from the code, change the last paragraph to show `x` and `x_predicted` values and describe the problem through them - would make it easier for the relevant people to find and understand the question more easily.

Comment: Thanks, made the edits. Hopefully it's more clear. What I'm doing is essentially simulating an optical flow so I went ahead and changed the title to reflect that.

Comment: Cool question. I look forward to looking at this more later this evening. Comments in your code explaining what each part is intended to do might help.

Comment: If you don't find the help you need here, try scicomp.se

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll add comments quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking into it too deeply, I think there are a couple of potential issues here:

**Violation of the Courant Condition**

The code you originally posted (I've edited it now) simulates a single timestep. I would not expect a cell 2 units away from your source cell to be activated in a single timestep. Doing so would voilate the [Courant condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courant%E2%80%93Friedrichs%E2%80%93Lewy_condition). From wikipedia:

> The principle behind the condition is that, for example, if a wave is moving across a discrete spatial grid and we want to compute its amplitude at discrete time steps of equal duration, then this duration must be less than the time for the wave to travel to adjacent grid points.

The Courant condition requires that uΔt/Δx <= 1 (for an explicit time-marching solver such as the one you've implemented). Plugging in u=2, Δt=1, Δx=1 gives 2, which is greater than 1, so you have a mathematical problem. The general way of fixing this problem is to make Δt smaller. You probably want something like:

```
x = x .- Δt*(v∇I .+ I∇v)  # I(x, y, t+dt)
```

**Missing gradients?**

I'm a little concerned about what's going on here:

```
Gvx = Interpolations.gradient(itpvx, i, j)  # gradient of vx in both directions
Gvy = Interpolations.gradient(itpvy, i, j)  # gradient of vy in both directions
∇vx_x[i, j] = Gvx[2];
∇vy_y[i, j] = Gvy[1];
```

You're able to pull two gradients out of both `Gvx` and `Gvy`, but you're only using one from each of them. Does that mean you're throwing information away?

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is likely to provide better help with this.

Comment: To address the missing gradients: Unless I'm messing up the math, the last term in the equation, `∇·v`, only utilizes two of the available gradients. `∇·v = (∂/∂x, ∂/∂y)·(vx, vy) = ∂vx/∂x + ∂vy/∂y`.

Comment: After a little reading up on the CFL condition you are 100% right. Thanks so much for your help!